# Replace everything between two BR tags with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I replace everything between:

```
<br />
<b>
```

and

```
<br />
```

For example:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: XXX in <b>YYY</b> on line <b>ZZZ<br />
<b>
```

Note: I know that I can turn of error reporting. But in this case I need to replace them from some existing HTML code.

```
$string_to_replace = '<div>
<p>Some content</p>
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: XXX in <b>YYY</b> on line <b>ZZZ</b><br />
<p>Some other content</p>
</div>';

$string_without_warnings = preg_replace('<br \/>(.*?)<br \/>', '', $string_to_replace);
```

Comment: You shouldn't try and process HTML with regexps. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to parse html using regex. See this famous SO post for an explanation why. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)

Having said that, what you have asked is of course possible, however I should point out that depending what you pass in, it could behave differently/buggy, hence why we discourage it.

First your regex: https://regex101.com/r/5fvuyi/1

```
<br \/>\n?(?<replace>.*)<br \/>
```

I used a named capture group, which you can see me referring to in the code. https://3v4l.org/uSVYZ

```
<?php

$string_to_replace = '<div>
<p>Some content</p>
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: XXX in <b>YYY</b> on line <b>ZZZ</b><br />
<p>Some other content</p>
</div>';

preg_match('#<br \/>\n?(?<replace>.*)<br \/>#', $string_to_replace, $match);
$new = str_replace($match['replace'], 'text replaced!', $string_to_replace);
echo $new;
```

Which outputs :

```
<div> 
    <p>Some content</p>
    <br />
    text replaced!<br />
    <p>Some other content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was useful for me. Also I used $string_without_warnings = preg_replace('#<br \/>\n?(?<replace>.*)<br \/>#', '', $string_to_replace); to replace the string completely.

Comment: Just remember, depending what you pass in, you could get unexpected results, if you know the string will be pretty consistent though you should be ok